# How to search for a value in the excel sheet using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not talking about VBScript. I'd like to get a cell or at least a row number after looking for particular string in the whole sheet.

Nothing works for me.. I was trying:

```
=MATCH("*LookingForThis*", A1:A3&B1:B3,0)
```

But that doesn't work.

Just to be sure, I was clear. I have a sheet like:

```
Foo1 Foo2 Foo3 Foo4 Foo5

Bar1 Bar2 Bar3 Bar4 Bar5

Tst1 Tst2 Tst3 Tst4 Tst5
```

When someone search for "Bar2" - the result will be "1" (as row #2), or a cell. But I need just a row. Need some help with this.

Thanks,

Comment: Why would it be `1` and not `2` for the second row?

Comment: Also your MATCH would work if you entered it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter as an array.

Comment: @ScottCraner because `1` is an index (it starts with `0`). `Ctrl-Shift-Enter `? I don't understand.. How?

Comment: INDEX() function starts with 1 not 0.  Ctrl-Shift-Enter is a method to force the formula into an array formula.  Enter the formula in the formula bar and instead of tab or Enter Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Excel will put `{}` around the formula indicating that it is an array formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner you're right. thanks, it actually worked with `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the Aggregate function for something like this:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$E$3)/($A$1:$E$3=G1),1)
```

[image]

You then can subtract the desired amount to get the correct index.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.